# getResource of external Maven library returns null on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my Android app I am consuming an external library as JAR via Maven. This JAR ships some additional resources (JNI libs) which I want to access via `ClassFromLibraryJar::class.java.getResource("").openStream()` but the resource is null. Do I need to somehow tell in the app project that these resources are embedded in the APK/AAB?

My real setup is using [this library](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/alphatab/alphaSkia-android/1.0.117/) (where I am also the author) and the simplified code for loading is:

```kotlin
val resource =
    AlphaSkiaAndroid::class.java.getResource("/native/android-arm64/libalphaskiajni.so")
if (resource != null) {
    resource.openStream().use {
        val tmpDir = java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("alphaskia");
        val tmpLib = tmpDir.resolve("libalphaskiajni.so").toFile();
        tmpLib.deleteOnExit()

        java.nio.file.Files.copy(it, tmpLib.toPath())
        System.load(tmpLib.getAbsolutePath())
    }
} else {
    throw IOException("Could not find JNI lib")
}
```

[image: The contained file]

The same library on Windows works fine and is structured the same but on Android fails. My app is built as debug (no pro-guard) and run on a real Android Device.

From what I've read loading the JNI lib from such a resource should also work on Android but I suspect that the JAR is not fully merged into the APK and the resources are filtered out.

Comment: I'm guessing that in Windows you are using a different version of the dynamic library built as a DLL since .so are not supported in Windows and it is a different build target than android arm64. Please clarify.

Comment: You are perfectly right about the need of having different libs for every OS and platform.  The problem is purely in accessing arbitrary binary JAR resources after being bundled into an APK. The same problem would occur with a simple PNG or JPG.